# Changing section headings

Tags: sectioning

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{aiaa-tc}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{First}

\subsection{Second}

\section{Conclusion}

\subsection{First}

\subsection{Second}

\section*{Appendices}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}

\subsection{First}

\subsubsection{First}

\subsubsection{Second}

\subsection{Second}

\subsubsection{First}

\subsubsection{Second}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

However, what I want to achieve is:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **Edited**

```
\documentclass[]{aiaa-tc}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesubsection   {\thesection.\@Alph\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{First}

\subsection{Second}

\section{Conclusion}

\subsection{First}

\subsection{Second}

\section*{Appendices}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}% 
{\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}% 
}
\renewcommand\thesubsection   {\@Alph\c@subsection}
\def\subsection@cntformat{\appendixname{} \thesubsection.\quad}
\makeatother

\subsection{First}

\subsubsection{First}

\subsubsection{Second}

\subsection{Second}

\subsubsection{First}

\subsubsection{Second}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this results in _Appendix II.A. First_, instead of _Appendix A. First_ and _II.A.1 First_ instead of _A.1 First_

Comment: For me I have what you ask : Appendix A. First . What is the version of your class .cls i have  v3.5

Comment: @Pietair answer edited

Comment: I am using aiaa-tc.cls v3.8. Your edited version does exactly what I want, thanks a lot!