# Change the display name of appendices with an article class

Tags: appendices

I'm willing to compile a document with appendices at the end of it. 
My work is currently made with an `article` class and, after loading the `appendix` package, I successfully get some appendices titles from `\section`s thanks to the `\appendix` command.
Unfortunately, what I get is this :

[image]

whereas I would like the header of the appendix to be like "Annexe A : Matrice des ventes"

I have tried to tinker with the followin command :

```
\usepackage{appendix}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\backmatter{
    \def\sectionmark##1{\markboth{%
        \ifnum  \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne  \@secapp\ \thesection:  \fi  ##1}{%
        \ifnum  \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne  \@secapp\ \thesection:  \fi  ##1}}%
    \def\subsectionmark##1{\relax}}
\makeatother
```

but it has proved unsuccessfull till now.

Comment: see this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238777/changing-section-headings/238787#238787

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it with the following code :

```
\appendix
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}% 
{\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}% 
}
\renewcommand\thesection   {\@Alph\c@section}
\def\section@cntformat{\appendixname{} \thesection\quad--\quad}
\makeatother
```

placed juste before my appendices.

Thank you @touhami for your link